# MariaDB import some table from full database dump file

Tags: mysql, mariadb

How can I import some table from full database dump file. For example I have a database dump file which include "categories,members,articles,prices,items". I just want to import "categories,members" from this dump file. Is it possible and how can I do this?

code is not working

```
mysql -u root -proot Mydatabase categories members < /data/fulldumpfile.dmp
```

Comment: so what are you using mariadb or mysql database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  You cannot specify a table on `mysql` commandline tool.

Does the dump file have `CREATE DATABASE Mydatabase`?  `DROP DATABASE Mydatabase`?  `USE Mydatabase`?  Depending on what is there, even saying `Mydatabase` on `mysql` may not take effect.

If you see only `USE`, then do

```
mysql -u root -proot  SomeOtherDB < /...
```

Then

```
RENAME TABLE  SomeOtherDB.categories TO DesiredDB.categories,
              SomeOtherDB.members    TO DesiredDb.members;
DROP DATABASE SomeOtherDB;
```

Otherwise, edit the dmp file.

(I don't think mariadb vs mysql matters for this question.)